# Calculating minimum distance between point and border using R

Tags: r, point, distance, proximity, borders

I want to generate the shortest distance between this province's capital to the China border. I want to calculate a minimum distance between a point and a border using  R. My code is as follows, but it does not work. I experience a few problems:

1. > Failed to install the rnaturalearthhires package.
2. `st_distance()` is not working

I am not sure what went wrong, or if my codes are missing something.

```r
#China border
install.packages("rnaturalearthhires", repos = "http://packages.ropensci.org", type = "source") #doesn't work
devtools::install_github("ropensci/rnaturalearthdata", force = TRUE) #doesn't work
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)
#import the limits of China
china <- ne_countries(scale=10, country="china", returnclass="sf")
mongolia<- readr ::read_csv(./mongolia.csv) #as the table shows
#calculation of the distance between the coast and our points
dist <- st_distance(china, mongolia)
```

[image]

```
setwd("C:/Users/wenra/Box Sync/2021_JF_files_LA_ISA_Merging_problems/2021_3jf_attempts")

capitals<-readr::read_csv("lonlat_province2_with_opencage.csv")

china<-st_read("./china_border/CHN_adm0.shp")

small<-capitals%>%
  select(province1,lat,lon)
#1 failed approach
dist <- st_distance(small, china) 
#2 failed approach
library(rgeos)
gDistance(small, china, byid = TRUE)

# 3 failed approach
small$col3 <- paste(small$lat, small$lon, sep=",") # comma separator
points<-small%>%select(col3)
install.packages("geosphere", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
library(geosphere)
dist<-dist2Line(points,china)
```

My dataset looks like

```
> head(small)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  province1               lat   lon
  <chr>                 <dbl> <dbl>
1 Seoul, South Korea     37.6 127. 
2 Incheon, South Korea   37.5 127. 
3 Ulaanbaatar, Mongolia  47.9 107. 
4 Khovd, Mongolia        48.1  91.3
5 Khuvsgul, Mongolia     43.6 110. 
6 Selenge, Mongolia      49.6 104.
```

Comment: Did you take a look at the answer of Spacedman detailled here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782488/r-calculating-the-shortest-distance-between-two-point-layers ?

Comment: I tried, yet, it does not work. I am not sure if my data need to be transformed or what other code I need?